# SwiftUI - How to make text appear using the button and then using the timer

Tags: swiftui

I would like text from the dictinary to appear when the button is pressed.
"Text1" is there at the beginning. If the button is pressed, a label with Text2 should appear under the start label. Then automatically a label with Text3 after 3 seconds. Originally I tried a list, but unfortunately I didn't get it.
It would be great if someone has an idea.

```
struct ContentView: View {

   var chats = [
                "Text1" : "Hello?",
                "Text2" : "Here!",
                "Text3" : "And here!",
               ]

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {

            VStack {
                Button(action: {}) {
                    Text("Button")
                }

                HStack {
                    Image (systemName: "faceid")
                    Text("\(chats["Text1"] ?? "Failure")")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your solution. Please try this.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var chats: [String: String] =  [
        "Text1" : "Hello?",
        "Text2" : "Here!",
        "Text3" : "And here!",
    ]

    @State var currentIndex: Int = 1


    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Button(action: {
                    self.currentIndex = self.currentIndex + 1
                    if self.currentIndex == 2 {
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
                            self.currentIndex = self.currentIndex + 1
                        }
                    }
                 print("Hello, World! Tapped")
                }) {
                    Text("Hello, World!")
                }
                HStack {
                    Image (systemName: "faceid")
                    Text("\(chats["Text\(currentIndex)"] ?? "Failure")")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. That works with one label. I would like to leave this label as it is and let another tap appear below it by tapping the button. And then after 3 seconds another one, which I address directly from the dictionary. (So ​​no loop).
I tried a list first, but I didn't get it the way I want it to. (I deleted the list of things from the code so that it is clearer).

Comment: `HStack {
                    Image (systemName: "faceid")
                    VStack {
                        Text("\(chats["Text1"] ?? "Failure")")
                        if currentIndex == 2 {
                            Text("\(chats["Text2"] ?? "Failure")")
                        } else if currentIndex == 3 {
                            Text("\(chats["Text2"] ?? "Failure")")
                            Text("\(chats["Text3"] ?? "Failure")")
                        }
                    }
                }`  Like this?

Comment: Just like that. Thank you. Thank you very much.